# How exclude <TR> table with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, pagination, html-table

I developed a pagination table with jQuery all things is work perfectly

but I have a problem, my table contains some TR I don't need to calculs them

I use ID in tbody table

The jQuery code

```js
$.fn.pageMe = function(opts) {
  var $this = this,
    defaults = {
      perPage: 7,
      showPrevNext: false,
      hidePageNumbers: false
    },
    settings = $.extend(defaults, opts);

  var listElement = $this;
  var perPage = settings.perPage;
  var children = listElement.children();
  var pager = $('.pager');

  if (typeof settings.childSelector != "undefined") {
    children = listElement.find(settings.childSelector);
  }

  if (typeof settings.pagerSelector != "undefined") {
    pager = $(settings.pagerSelector);
  }

  var numItems = children.size();
  var numPages = Math.ceil(numItems / perPage);

  pager.data("curr", 0);

  if (settings.showPrevNext) {
    $('<li><a href="#" class="prev_link">«</a></li>').appendTo(pager);
  }

  var curr = 0;
  // Added class and id in li start
  while (numPages > curr && (settings.hidePageNumbers == false)) {
    $('<li id="pg' + (curr + 1) + '" class="pg"><a href="#" class="page_link">' + (curr + 1) + '</a></li>').appendTo(pager);
    curr++;
  }
  // Added class and id in li end

  if (settings.showPrevNext) {
    $('<li><a href="#" class="next_link">»</a></li>').appendTo(pager);
  }

  pager.find('.page_link:first').addClass('active');
  pager.find('.prev_link').hide();
  if (numPages <= 1) {
    pager.find('.next_link').hide();
  }
  pager.children().eq(1).addClass("active");

  children.hide();
  children.slice(0, perPage).show();
  if (numPages > 3) {
    $('.pg').hide();
    $('#pg1,#pg2,#pg3').show();
    $("#pg3").after($("<li class='ell'>").html("<span>...</span>"));
  }

  pager.find('li .page_link').click(function() {
    var clickedPage = $(this).html().valueOf() - 1;
    goTo(clickedPage, perPage);
    return false;
  });
  pager.find('li .prev_link').click(function() {
    previous();
    return false;
  });
  pager.find('li .next_link').click(function() {
    next();
    return false;
  });

  function previous() {
    var goToPage = parseInt(pager.data("curr")) - 1;
    goTo(goToPage);
  }

  function next() {
    goToPage = parseInt(pager.data("curr")) + 1;
    goTo(goToPage);
  }

  function goTo(page) {
    var startAt = page * perPage,
      endOn = startAt + perPage;

    // Added few lines from here start

    $('.pg').hide();
    $(".ell").remove();
    var prevpg = $("#pg" + page).show();
    var currpg = $("#pg" + (page + 1)).show();
    var nextpg = $("#pg" + (page + 2)).show();
    if (prevpg.length == 0) nextpg = $("#pg" + (page + 3)).show();
    if (prevpg.length == 1 && nextpg.length == 0) {
      prevpg = $("#pg" + (page - 1)).show();
    }
    if (curr > 3) {
      if (page > 1) prevpg.before($("<li class='ell'>").html("<span>...</span>"));
      if (page < curr - 2) nextpg.after($("<li class='ell'>").html("<span>...</span>"));
    }
    currpg.addClass("active").siblings().removeClass("active");

    // Added few lines till here end


    children.css('display', 'none').slice(startAt, endOn).show();

    if (page >= 1) {
      pager.find('.prev_link').show();
    } else {
      pager.find('.prev_link').hide();
    }

    if (page < (numPages - 1)) {
      pager.find('.next_link').show();
    } else {
      pager.find('.next_link').hide();
    }

    pager.data("curr", page);


  }
};


$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#myTable').pageMe({
    pagerSelector: '#myPager',
    showPrevNext: true,
    hidePageNumbers: false,
    perPage: 2
  });

});
```

So, with this code takes all `<tr>` in my table, but I need to exclude some tr how can I do it ?

I try to give Id to the TR that I need it but without result

Comment: Why do you need to exclude a TR? IS the TR in the tbody? Can you just remove them?

Comment: @epascarello Yes is it in the tbody, I developed a table that have information if you click in a button that give other information (this's the TR that I need to exclude it )

Comment: @freedomn-m the ID `#myPager` is in the UL (pagination) if you need something, I can add the code

Comment: for example i give a class like this `excl` for the TRs that I need to exclude it, what the next ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming this is your table:

```
<table id='myPager'>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>row 1</td></td>
    <tr><td>row 2</td></td>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

and your code does:

```
$(opts.pagerSelector).find("tbody>tr").slice(1, 10).hide();
```

then, add a class to the rows you  want to exclude, I'll use "excluded" here, but you might want to add as an option:

```
<table id='myPager'>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>row 1</td></td>
    <tr><td class='excluded'>row 2</td></td>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

then check for that class:

```
$(opts.pagerSelector).find("tbody>tr:not(.excluded)").slice(1, 10).hide();
```

---

Update: from additional details in the question:

change

```
var children = listElement.children();
```

to

```
var children = listElement.children().not(".excluded");
```

Comment: How I can add it in my jquery code ( in the post ) ?

Comment: I give the class to my TR, but I don't know what I need to add in my jQuery code ?

Comment: You haven't provided the code for `.pageMe` - where's that defined?

Comment: There's nothing to add to your jquery code in the post as your jquery code in the post doesn't do the pagination, it sets it up via a plugin call '.pageMe' which you implied you had written yourself by asserting *"I **developed** a pagination table"*.

Comment: Updated answer.  Not sure about this line `pager.children().eq(1).addClass("active");` as it doesn't use the `children` var and sets the first row to active *before* hiding/showing them, which doesn't seem right.  But all the others (that I noticed) correctly use the var.